# Eclipse e4 RCP - setting titlebar text at runtime

Tags: rcp, e4

I would like to be able to change the titlebar text at runtime. Typically I want to do this when my application opens a file, so that I will have Application Name - File Name in the titlebar.

I've read about people using an `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` to get hold of the `IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer`, and then using that to set the title, but I don't actually know where or how to get hold of the `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`, or even whether this is a class I need to write.

Currently, the title is set via the appName property in my plugin.xml only.

Can someone please show an example if its usage?

Comment: Is this a pure e4 application (you are using the Application.e4xmi and no compatibility layer)? All the things you mention are the old style 3.x API.

Comment: Yes it is pure e4. I guess this is why it wasn't making much sense to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting the label on the top level `MWindow` of your app:

```java
@Inject
MApplication application;
@Inject
EModelService modelService;

....

MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("id of your top window", application);

window.setLabel("new label");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the `modelService.find` method seems to require a String id and an MUIElement object. What should the second argument be?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the EModelService to find the MWindow by ID, is to use injection.  In this way, it'll find the parent (and active, though that might be redundant) Window in the Context of the Control that is performing the action (File-Chooser in your case):

```java
@Inject
@Active
private MWindow window;
```